# WPF DataGrid is filled except when I use LINQ to filter its items

Tags: wpf, linq, data-binding, datagrid, filtering

I've got a simple WPFToolkit `DataGrid`:

```
<Grid>
    <dg:DataGrid Name="theDataGrid"/>
</Grid>
```

And in code behind a simple `Contact` class:

```
public class Contact
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public Contact(string firstName, string lastName)
    {
        this.FirstName = firstName;
        this.LastName = lastName;
    }
}
```

In my main constructor in code behind, I build a `List` collection and bind it to my `DataGrid`:

```
List<Contact> contacts = new List<Contact>();
contacts.Add(new Contact("John", "Tester"));
contacts.Add(new Contact("Jill", "Tester"));
contacts.Add(new Contact("Joe", "Tester"));
contacts.Add(new Contact("Jimmy", "Nontester"));
theDataGrid.ItemsSource = contacts;
```

and that works fine, but if I filter these contacts with LINQ like this:

```
List<Contact> contacts = new List<Contact>();
contacts.Add(new Contact("John", "Tester"));
contacts.Add(new Contact("Jill", "Tester"));
contacts.Add(new Contact("Joe", "Tester"));
contacts.Add(new Contact("Jimmy", "Nontester"));

var filteredContacts = contacts.Where(contact => contact.LastName.StartsWith("T"));
theDataGrid.ItemsSource = filteredContacts;
```

Then my `DataGrid` is populated, but the fields are all empty (!). For example, in the above case, my `DataGrid` has three rows which are all empty. Strangely when debugging, `filteredContacts` contains four items.

How can I use LINQ to filter my custom objects AND get them to display in my `DataGrid`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i would try two things :

1. Change

   ```
   theDataGrid.ItemsSource = filteredContacts;
   ```

   to

   ```
   theDataGrid.ItemsSource = filteredContacts.ToList();
   ```
2. The second would be to use a View and filter on the View.

   ```
   ListCollectionView view = (ListCollectionView)CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(contacts);

   view.Filter = delegate(object item) { return (item as Contact).LastName.StartsWith("T"); };

   theDataGrid.ItemsSource = view;
   ```

Comment: The CollectionViewSource is the best way to go, it's made to do this exact thing. I have an example on my site if your looking http://www.jarloo.com/excel-like-autofilter-in-wpf/